# Custom font on iOS7 app which supports iOS 6

Tags: ios7, ios6, fonts, customization

I have made an app which has several custom fonts, but i'm struggling to make it work on ios6 devices, i have added them in myApp-Info.plist and it works without any problem on labels and buttons and everywhere except uiwebviews in ios7 , but in ios 6 it looks like the default font in everywhere and there is no change throughout the whole app in fonts. After searching  couple of weeks, still haven't find any answer that would work.

Here is my code for assigning a font to label :

```
 titleLable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"B Yekan" size:17];
```

Comment: how you are assigning fontstyle to the label,button,post the code in question.

Comment: i assign them using macro or the simple way , like this :     [callButtonLable.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"B Yekan" size:17]]; or for labels   titleLable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"B Yekan" size:17];

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem, also, and found that in iOS 7, font names aren't case-sensitive; i.e., I was trying to use "ChunkFive-Roman", which worked in iOS 7 even though my code said "Chunkfive-Roman".

However, this doesn't work in iOS 6... I was getting the default font instead. Changing the font name to "ChunkFive-Roman" fixed it so that that the text was appearing correctly in both. (Note -- was using Simulator in both cases).

Comment: Yes you right. i had the same case sensitive issue. and it is done i there was just an issue with one capital character. and it was working fine on iOS 7 and not working in iOS 6. strange issues. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the rules in [this link](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-use-custom-font-in-iphone-sdk.html), once you do it there u go..

1. Add  your custom font into your project , i.e. Dragged the font's ttf file (`CALIBRIZ_0.TTF`) into your resource folder from finder and check the "*copy file to project folder*" option. )
2. Edit `Info.plist`: Add a new entry with the key Fonts provided by application.
3. For each of your files, add the file name to this array (*Fonts provided by application*)

Now set font to your label:

```
 MyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:16];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.builtwithlogic.com/post/73503283890/installing-custom-fonts-on-iphone-and-ipad-ios-devices

Covers how to add fonts - Little confused though by your question you specifically mention iOS6 as the problem and UIWebView - Be interested to know what you mean by that piece?

Have you tried setting the fonts using UIAppearance ? or are you subclassing and amending the fonts as it could be that you've not done it right there. Could you supply some code showing how you setting you custom fonts throughout the app?

If you haven't already I'd ensure you've followed the steps in that email and then add a custom category to UIFont to pass back a specific font. If you haven't already done so I would also set the fonts in UIAppearance for your labels, Titles etc this is the cleanest and most efficient way to do it throughout your application as you only need set it one and you can set differently based on how a for example Label is presented -in a tableview in a navigation bar etc.

here's a link to the official docs 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Appreciate this question is old but love to know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the custom font would work in iOS7, but not iOS6.

The solution for me was to use the true font name not the filename.
To do this check the font name as shown in OSX's FontBook.

iOS7 allowed me to use the the filename (less the .ttf suffix), but iOS6 wanted the true font name as shown in FontBook.

For example for a font named CustomFont.ttf .....

I followed all the steps listed by others here to add the font to my app, but then used it by referencing it as @"CustomFont".

When I added the font to my mac and looked at it in FontBook (mac utility), it was actually named @"Custom font" - with a space and a lower case letter.

Hopefully this helps someone else out there :-)

Answer (score -3):

iOS 6 cannot do custom fonts.  That is a new feature only available in iOS 7.